# Boost serialization text archive are Cross-language?

Tags: java, boost, archive, boost-serialization

Hy...I try to explain better my question...
Im using boost serialization text archive before sending data over TCP connection...
Now I need to pass the received data to a Java application...so I would know if the serialized stream is composed only by the data or by the data + boost serialization(tag, code, etc.)...
In this case my only chance to transfer the data to the java application, is to filter them before transfering?thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know Boost serialization text archive uses custom formatting.

For instance it puts serialization archive version number in the output. So you will have to filter these kind of data with Java.

Even if you have used boost binary archive you would not be able to deserialize it with Java.

So the answer to your question is boost serialization mechanism and Java are **not** compatible.

Try using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) as serialization format if you have to use text based communicatoin which makes life easier.

Comment: Ok thanks...do you know if I can solve the problem using the xml archive??Or if exists a java library which is able to deserialize a boost serialization?